# Passing info from Vuex module to component after axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to create Vue.js based app. Here's my scenario. I have a component in which I have a popup to create an 'expense' entry. When clicked on the 'save' button, I call a function defined in the Vuex module which deals with the api call to save the entry. like this

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name : 'CreateExpense',
    data(){
        return {
            expense : {
                expense : null,
                amount : 0,
                comment : null
            }
        }
    },
    methods : {
        ...mapActions(['addExpense']),
        saveExpense(){
            this.addExpense( this.expense );
        }
    }
}
```

my vuex module has this

```
const actions = {
    addExpense({commit},expense){
        axios.post( env.API_URL + 'save-expense',expense)
        .then( response => commit('addExpense',expense) )        
    }
};
```

my problem is I am not able to figure how to pass the information to the component that this api call is completed and expense state object is updated so that it can close the popup opened there. I wanted the .catch/.then are dealt with in the module itself instead of component, and in the component ,just closing the popup + some alert message. Please point me to some direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name : 'CreateExpense',
    data(){
        return {
            expense : {
                expense : null,
                amount : 0,
                comment : null
            }
        }
    },
    methods : {
        ...mapActions(['addExpense']),
        saveExpense(){
            this.addExpense( this.expense );
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['expense'])
    },
    watch: {
      expense (val) {
        if (val) //close popup modal
      }
    }
}
```

store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions: { ... },
  state: { ... },
  getters: {
    expense: ({expense}) => expense
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately (sans mapGetters)

In your store:

```
addExpense ({commit}, expense) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(env.API_URL + 'save-expense', expense)
    .then(response => {
      commit('addExpense', expense);
      resolve(response); // THIS WILL RETURN TO YOUR COMPONENT
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    })
  })
}
```

And in your component:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.myMethod()
},

methods: {
  myMethod: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch('addExpense')
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response', response) // SHOULD GET VALUE FROM RESOLVE
    }) 
  }
}
```